# Add image and text dynamically by user input(user is providing data) in Android Custom LIst View

Tags: android-listview

Explanation:-
I have a form in which user is providing his firstname and lastname. On click of submit button on the form containing firstname and lastname, this firstname and lastname will be displayed in the first row of list then second user will perform the same task and then that firstname and lastname of the second user will be displayed in the second row of the list.

Comment: do you need this by using SQLite database or just by using ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write code in a below way to achieve your target....

```
  public class Restaurant extends Activity {
  List<Restaurant> model=new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
  RestaurantAdapter adapter=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

    save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.restaurants);

    adapter=new RestaurantAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Restaurant r=new Restaurant();
      EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
      EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);

      r.setName(name.getText().toString());
      r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());

      RadioGroup types=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.types);

      switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.sit_down:
          r.setType("sit_down");
          break;

        case R.id.take_out:
          r.setType("take_out");
          break;

        case R.id.delivery:
          r.setType("delivery");
          break;
      }

      adapter.add(r);
    }
  };

  class RestaurantAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> {
    RestaurantAdapter() {
      super(LunchList.this, R.layout.row, model);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
      View row=convertView;
      RestaurantHolder holder=null;

      if (row==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        holder=new RestaurantHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
      }
      else {
        holder=(RestaurantHolder)row.getTag();
      }

      holder.populateFrom(model.get(position));

      return(row);
    }
  }

  static class RestaurantHolder {
    private TextView name=null;
    private TextView address=null;
    private ImageView icon=null;

    RestaurantHolder(View row) {
      name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
      address=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
      icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }

    void populateFrom(Restaurant r) {
      name.setText(r.getName());
      address.setText(r.getAddress());

      if (r.getType().equals("sit_down")) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_red);
      }
      else if (r.getType().equals("take_out")) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_yellow);
      }
      else {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_green);
      }
    }
  }
```

I recommend you to use this code:

```
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/tree/master/05-FancyList/LunchList
```

to get started and to develop your program as you need

Comment: Thanks Mr KL Amit Suri. Thanks for your help and sharing this wonderful example on github.